# How to fix these problems found from chrome.exe --diagnostics

Tags: google-chrome

first time user here. I recently re-installed Window 10 Pro onto my computer, and the first thing I did was to install Google Chrome using Edge (hmmm), and synced my profiles onto chrome. And then something weird happened. I personally always use an 1Gbps ethernet connection, and found that chrome seemed to be loading very slowly, sometimes lost connection because it took to long to load a webpage. I searched online and landed on the Chromium OS page, where I followed the steps and get to here.

I hope if there are any awesome people out here to see how to fix these problems, thanks. :D

[image: Diagnostic Results]

[image: Task Manager Usage (When not opened, just opened diagnostics)]

[image: Windows Build Version]

Comment: Since it is a fresh install of chrome some of those file location will not be created yet, use chrome for a month then try diagnostics again and compare results.

Comment: @Moab ok, but this is the first time I had ever encountered this issue with chrome. D;